# Create break between geometry lines, Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an application in Three.JS which has a geometry to which the user can add vertices. A line is drawn between the vertices of the geometry using `line = new THREE.Line(geometry);` Then, whenever I do something like `geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));`, the points `<x, y, z>` are added to the path of the line.

I want to know if there's a way to make a break between lines. For instance, say I want a line between `<10, 20, 30>` and `<30, 10, 20>`, and then I wanted another line between `<45, 15, 100>` and `<20, 30, 40>`, but without either of the lines being connected. For instance, if I pushed all of those vectors in order, there would be a line connecting `<30, 10, 20>` to `<45, 15, 100>` automatically. I want to know if I can split these lines without having to make a new geometry or a new line. Is there some type of thing I can push to `geometry.vertices` that would make a break? Or any other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, say I have a `geometry` with a corresponding `line`. When I need to make a break, I copy the vertices of the main `geometry` to a new, temporary one, make a temporary line based off of that, and add it to the image. Then, remove vertices from the original `geometry`. I also need to remove the old `line` from the scene, as it can't plot `geometry` with no points, so custom code has to be written to fit that.